# Invalid URL in ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-online

While adding items in the ArcGIS Online platform, an error appears with the message:

> Invalid URL

The file I am trying to upload is a shapefile I receive from a client. It had no defined projection so I exported the shapefile using ArcMap in WGS84, to make it compatible with the ArcGIS online platform. I have tried to upload it in Firefox, Chrome and Explorer, and the same message appears: Invalid URL.

The file is a .zip with the shapefile extensions (.cpg/.dbf/.prj/.sbn/.sbx/.shp/.shp.xml/.shx).

I have tried to "Add item" inside the Content page, and the Invalid URL message appears. When I try to upload it on My Map - "Add Layer From File", the message is "Unable to import Shapefile"

Any solutions?

Comment: Please edit your question so it provides additional informations on the source of the data, the way you add it, if there's anything different (source, size, codecs) with this file from the others, etc. Currently any answer is guesswork.

Comment: Thank you Erik for the reply. I have already edited the question with further details. Can you help me in any way?

Comment: are you able to add the new shp into Pro? To make sure everything is there possibly import into a geodatabase and export a shp out?